# Coded UI Test: How to enter a string, that contains tabs & line breaks, into a text input field without jumping to the next DOM element

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, coded-ui-tests

I have a string that contains tabs "\t" that are necessary to enter into a text field (because it is copied from an Excel table).
When the Coded UI runs my captured manual step, it jumps to the next DOM element exactly where the "\t" is.

How can I prevent Coded UI from doing this and enter "\t" into the text input?

I also have a line breaks "\n" in the string. I haven't gotten that far to see if the Coded UI will enter it in the text input field or not. Anyone has experience on this?

Neither of the following worked:

- public string UIPleasecopyyourExcelWEditText = "Column_A Column_B    Column_C\n31632 CompanyName_1   2017";
- public string UIPleasecopyyourExcelWEditText = "Column_A\tColumn_B\tColumn_C\n31632\tCompanyName_1\t2017\n";

We even tried executing JS using a driver but we couldn't find the "driver" because it's hidden inside the Coded UI library somewhere.

We use Selenium Chrome Driver for this test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chen, 
This is a Selenium specific behavior I believe. Do try to run the same tests in IE 11 without Selenium. In my experience CodedUI treats {TAB} as a tab key press. Please see below for more details. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.7.2

Do let me know how it behaves with CodedUI/IE 11.

Comment: Thanks but we don't deliver on IE (it's an internal constraint)

Comment: Don't deliver it on IE, at least you'll know what's the exact problem... Try making a small sample...